# No more question closures on a booming economics.SE

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, review

If you look at the history of the close review queue, you might notice that after 2022 Apr 1, all votes in that queue were made by myself, another user and a mod. A question needs 5 non-mod votes to close.

I think there still are bad/off-topic questions, so please vote to close when necessary.

Comment: Yes could not agree more. Also, I plan look into the possibility to reduce required votes for closing from 5-3 this is being contemplated by multiple stacks (e.g. see [here on Aviation Meta](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4335/should-we-move-to-3-close-votes)). For a small stack like Economics.se 5 seem to be too low.

Comment: The close review queue doesn't capture votes cast directly from the post (using the "Close" link). Nor does it record the person initiating the close, I believe. But I agree that the site needs more active reviewers. (I regrettably am one who's not as active as I used to.)

Comment: @HerrK. Very high concentration in the [Steward](https://economics.stackexchange.com/help/badges/83/steward) industry...

Comment: That link is "status-completed". Pretty sure it's 3 at DiY. Make it happen here, +1.

Comment: If y'all think the close vote threshold should be lowered for Economics.SE, I'd suggest posting a new Q&A focused specifically around that request. (Since this question is just sort of a general PSA to vote to close when necessary, we can't really use the votes on this question as a sign of community consensus to make that change.)