# Should we reduce the number of votes required to close from 5 to 3 close votes?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

Economics.SE is relatively small stack with few high rep users. This creates problem as it often takes quite long for questions that do not fit or are low quality to get closed. This seems to be recognized problem judging from number of upvotes [here](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2194/no-more-question-closures-on-a-booming-economics-se).

There is currently opportunity for stack exchange sites to switch from 5 to 3 close vote model.

Should we implement this model here as well? The model has [pros & cons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364007/testing-three-vote-close-and-reopen-on-13-network-sites), but for a small site as ours I believe it would be overall a positive change.

Currently even [larger sites](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14133/testing-3-vote-close-and-reopen) than ours contemplate this model since lack of people who regularly go through review queue seems to be problem SE-wide problem (probably it should not surprise us economists that service with positive externality is undersupplied :p).

Please let me know what the community thinks about this proposal and whether I should go forward with requesting the change.

**Edit** added status review tag to bring this to the CM attention, can you please make the switch? There seems to be large enough support.

Comment: With enough reputation, you can see the "recent" close voters in the [review queue](https://economics.stackexchange.com/review). When I am writing this, the 6th most recent voter last voted on Mar 31st. Of the top five, one is a moderator (:

Comment: It has been a week, there are no votes against, and more people voted for than actually turn up to close votes, so I would say this has passed.

Comment: @Giskard please have little bit patience, I will deal with the request to CMs for changes over the weekend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After review, it looks like your site would be an excellent candidate to have the close vote requirement lowered. We have that updated only to require three votes for closure now.

Answer (score 8):

I think this would be a beneficial change.  It doesn't give a good impression of the site when low-quality questions take a long time to be closed, and perhaps in the meantime receive low-quality answers. It would seem sensible at the same time to reduce the requirement for re-open votes from 5 to 3 to avoid delay in reopening if a closed question has been improved.

Comment: its my understanding that it automatically affects reopen votes as well, but I will double check with CMs

Answer (score 7):

Yes, I'm strongly in favor of that!